# Running python script from PHP, works untill I add Playwright module

Tags: python, php, playwright-python

I'm running a python script from my webserver initiated by PHP. If the python script is simple, for example, print Hello World, it will execute flawlessly.

However, as soon as I add the playwright library and do anything, the server will not run the script...

Does anyone have a quick fix?

I am running test.php which is:

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command); 

echo $output;

?>
```

If test.py =

```
print(5)
```

Then output equals "5"

If test.py =

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    context = browser.new_context()

    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()

    # Go to 
    page.goto("https://inzamelhelden.nl/beheer/rapportageplus.php")


    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run(playwright)

print(5)
```

Then there is no output. The script runs fine if I run it from the command line of the server.

I don't know how to check what the error is, the script runs fine from command line and there is no php in the error log. I am running plesk

EDIT:

[![Running from the console][1]][1]

Here I am running the following script from the console:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    context = browser.new_context()

    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()

    # Go to 
    page.goto("https://inzamelhelden.nl/beheer/rapportageplus.php")


    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run(playwright)

print(5)
```

As seen, it runs and outputs the 5. However I know run it from the PHP script which is ran from a html page on the website.

Now changing the script to

```
print(5)
```

I run it from the console:

```
~~@~~:/var/www/vhosts/~~/httpdocs# python3 test.py
5
```

Censored for privacy reasons. I know run that script from the html page and:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

It outputs the 5.

This is pretty much everything I have. The php error log shows empty, the console does not return a error for both scripts. The only thing that changes is the usage of playwright
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXiB8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/upfgg.png

Comment: Thanks! `downloadpath = "controlebestanden/" + ` looks like invalid syntax. Are you sure this is the correct script?

Comment: Yes! I have reduced the script not to show any important information. If I remove that line I still have the problem. I think it is a permission issue

Comment: I'd edit the post to remove that line, then--the variable is unused and the program won't run, period, so it's a non-starter. If I do that, the PHP program works fine for me. Can you add whatever details are needed to help reproduce the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on Ubuntu 22, without changing permissions.

I've removed the syntax error and simplified the code to a minimal, reproducible example. Try running this on your machine.

`test.py`:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.example.com")
    print(page.text_content("h1").strip())
    browser.close()
```

`test.php`:

```php
<?php
echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("python3 test.py"));
?>
```

Terminal output showing permissions, relevant version information and the script working both when run directly as well as through a localhost server:

```
$ python3 -m pip freeze | grep play
playwright==1.28.0
$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.6
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2023 22:56:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
$ ls -l test*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g2 g2  61 Apr  7 11:24 test.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g2 g2 265 Apr  7 11:23 test.py
$ php test.php
Example Domain
$ php -S localhost:8000 &
[1] 211749
$ [Fri Apr  7 11:57:58 2023] PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started
$ curl http://localhost:8000/test.php
[Fri Apr  7 11:58:10 2023] 127.0.0.1:39170 Accepted
[Fri Apr  7 11:58:14 2023] 127.0.0.1:39170 [200]: GET /test.php
Example Domain

[Fri Apr  7 11:58:14 2023] 127.0.0.1:39170 Closing
```

Comment: I am running it from the /var/www/httpdocs directory. If I then run the script from my website www.example.com/test.php it unfortunately does not run..

Comment: By "it does not run", do you get an error... or what happens, exactly? And it _does_ work when the Python script is just `print(5)`? I don't see what difference it should make whether the Python script uses Playwright or not, syntax error aside (please run my Python code rather than yours to eliminate that and update your post to show your exact code, so it's clear that it's not just a syntax error problem).

Comment: 'By "it does not run", do you get an error... or what happens, exactly? And it does work when the Python script is just print(5)?'

This is exactly what happens, yes.. I'm making an update to the opening post. I am not sure where to find any errors on this

Comment: I have added to the opening post

Comment: OK, thanks. For starters, your Playwright code isn't printing anything related to the Playwright logic, so you might want to start by actually printing the page content to prove it works. Did you try running my code? I still can't reproduce this if I use your website. Did you try moving the print line by line from the top to see where it fails/stops/crashes, if it does fail/stop/crash? I don't follow your response to my question--I'm asking if there's an error, and what happens, not a "yes/no" question.

Comment: I missed your code. Thanks. So while trying the print line-by-line it works after the import, then immediately fails after:

`with sync_playwright() as playwright:'

Comment: Is there an error in the server log or does the script die silently? Almost certainly, there's a log somewhere that will tell you the problem with the import. If it just kicks the script back to the terminal silently, it could be a memory issue.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/QeKDUc0)

These are all the logs I can find. error_log seems to be only filled by PHP errors. Nothing to be found about the script though

A memory issue could be but it runs fine on the terminal

Comment: Perhaps run your Python script as `import sys; print("foobar", file=sys.stderr)` then search your logs for `foobar` so you know where errors are logged to. Then run it again with Playwright and see what it says. Yeah, the memory issue is unlikely and would only be if there's somehow a different amount allocated when the Python script is run as a subprocess. That's the only way I know of to have Python ungracefully dump you back to the terminal without some sort of stack trace, assuming you're not swallowing the error, which doesn't appear to be the case since you don't have any `except`s.

Comment: I can't find foobar in any log. I am logging of for tonight but will keep searching

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like a log visibility problem may be happening here. `echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("python3 test.py 2>&1"));` should help you log the stderr so you can see what's going on.

Comment: I've tried but still nothing..